# How to show recently added posts to my custom post category?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I and working on a wordpress website and want to show Title with its permalink of recently added posts in the my custom post category, i have tried many testimonials from the web but failed.

Any one here, suggest me php code to show the custom post type category-recently added.

Thanks

Comment: do you want to list recent posts in the custom category you created in the front end ?

Comment: nope, i want to display recent custom post types POST in my custom template

Comment: how many recent custom posts you want to display ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $post_type = 'your custom post type';
    $posts_per_page = '5';
    $queryObject = new WP_Query( 'post_type='. $post_type .'&posts_per_page='. $posts_per_page );
    // The Loop!
    if ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
?>
        <ul>
<?php
            while ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
                $queryObject->the_post();
?>
                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> </a></li><?php
            }
?>
        </ul>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Hope this helps you